# Is this have any performance issue of using more packages for any react web application?

Tags: reactjs, performance, package

I have been doing a team project for making a mid level coffee shop website recently on react stack. Will it degrade the performance of my site if I use more react packages?

Comment: Did you measure it?

Comment: https://bundlephobia.com/ refer this

Comment: Yes, it will increase the build size. You can use code splitting, this will  split your code into small chunks. Please don't apply this directly to your routes.

Answer (score 0):

as more dependencies your site has, the bundle size increases so the load time increases.